# Trying to run my flutter app on a real device using vs code

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

this is the error and the flutter doctor results

[image]

[image]

Comment: please include all error messages/code as formatted text not as images.

Comment: You should post text content as text, not an image as its not searchable, hard to read and we cannot copy it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use proxy or vpn to gradle can download all needed dependencies. you can use Tor or other things that you want.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that Gradle is either blocked in your country or it is filtered.
using a VPN will fix it.
consider using Proton VPN which works fine.

Comment: If you ask questions and make suggestions... use the comment section and not the answer section. This is not giving a resolution/solution to the question itself

Comment: I forgit this , it works .. thanks you so much